# Separate keystore for and app from old keystore with multiple apps

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore, google-developers-console

I have 5 apps signed with one keystore file. Now I want to create a separate keystore for one app and keep the package id unchanged.

How can I do it?

Comment: different alias for each app

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. But, you just need to use your preferred tool (openssl, keytool, keystoreexplorer) to export each key and import it into a new keystore per application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a keystore with single alias or key, then it means all apps are signed with same key. In this case, it is not possible to change the key to sign the app for submitting in Google's Play console. You must always use the same key to sign the apps for submitting updates.

Comment: What if I all 5 alias are different? Is there any way to create a separate keystore file of one alias?

Comment: I don't think that is possible either, but I'm not sure. Why do you want to separate it into multiple files?

Comment: I want to transfer the ownership to another company

Comment: If the passwords for each alias are different, you can provide password of the keystore and the password of that alias only. But if the password of all alias are same, you will need to share key of all apps.